# Finding the length of an equal side of an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry

Consider an isosceles triangle $DEF$ with $DE = DF$. $K$ is a point on $DF$ such that $EK = 50$. Let $M$ be a point on the line segment $EK$ such that $EM:MK = 16:9$. If $\angle DMK = 2 \times \angle DFE$, find $DE$.

I have no idea how to start. Originally, I thought that the given conditions are not sufficient to determine the side length. However, after drawing the graph in the computer, I found that if $DE = 40$, all the other conditions are satisfied. While if I use other values as $DE$, I cannot draw such a graph. I am guessing there is a method to find the value? Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found lengths of segments $ME$ and $MK$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
$$\angle DFE=\angle DEF=\alpha\implies \angle DMK=2\alpha$$
Observe,
$$\angle DME=\angle EDK=180^{\circ}-2\alpha$$

So, we have,
$$\triangle DME\sim\triangle KDE  \implies \frac{ME}{DE}=\frac{DE}{EK}\implies DE=\sqrt{32\cdot 50}$$
$$\therefore\; DE=40$$

Comment: Thank you! I was so focused on using the sine and cosine law and I forgot the basic techniques!